# JS mongoDB sort by previousItem property (parent-child relationship)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting

I have an item collection with documents that have an order that matters and it may change (i.e. the creation time or id cannot be used for sorting).

I thought that adding a previous/nextItem properties may be a solution

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "itemC",
  previousItem : 2,
  nextItem : 0
}

{
  id: 0
  name: "itemB", 
  previousItem : 1,
  nextItem : null
}

{
  id: 2,
  name: "itemA",
  previousItem : null,
  nextItem : 1
}
```

I would like to retrieve the records based on a sort parameter that traverses the previousItem property.

Above collection should be returned as:

```
{
  id: 2,
  name: "itemA",
  previousItem : null,
  nextItem : 1
}

{
  id: 1,
  name: "itemC",
  previousItem : 2,
  nextItem : 0
}

{
  id: 0
  name: "itemB", 
  previousItem : 1,
  nextItem : null
}
```

Comment: Why not just add an order property? For example, first item's order=1, next has order=2, etc.  Linked lists are great for storing large ordered lists in memory, but typically suboptimal for read performance (especially random access reads).  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: To quote the wikipedia article "simple linked lists by themselves do not allow random access to the data, or any form of efficient indexing".

Comment: @MattTannahill The problem with this solution is that the order frequently changes and I would need to update the order property for all items when I change/insert a new one.

Comment: Fair.  It sounds like we must optimize the write performance in this scenario.  This makes a linked list a good choice.  However, as stated on Wikipedia, there isn't a way to index a linked list, which means you will never be able to read efficiently.  Your read performance is going to be abysmal with a linked list.  The only way to traverse a linked list is to fetch an item, check the next previous property, fetch that item, check its next previous property, etc.  You're going to have a lot network and I/O latency.

Comment: However, you could do a set-based, conditional update to get decent write performance with the order approach.  If I needed to insert an item at order 2, I would run an update like: query {order: {$gte: 2} }, update to increment the documents after the new document: { $inc: { order: 1}}.  Then I would insert a document with order with 2.  Remember, the order property values don't need to be contiguous.  They can skip numbers.  They just need to be in the correct order.  So you should never have to update order values if you remove an item.

Comment: @MattTannahill Not having to actually set the order 1,2,3,4,... may help in this case. I could just try to find a number between the two adjacent indices.. let's assume I insert an item between 2 and 3: It should work to set the order to (2+3)/2 =2.5. This way it would never be necessary to update any of the orders. Do you see any drawback with that?

Comment: You run up against the 17 digit JS limitation for decimals in floats pretty quickly using subdivision.

Answer (score 1):

So here are the basic assumptions for the sorting index:
1. The index property is a string in order to allow for more then 17 digits.
2. only use the last digit of the adjacent items to calculate the new index in order to avoid calculations with more than 17 digits. Algorithm (the following values are all strings):

```
indices:
I1
I2
I3

add item between 1 and 2 --> 
   is there an integer between the two values?
   yes --> use it as the new index
   no --> use the lower index and append 05, add 00 to lower index

eval (1,2) --> no

I100
I105
I2
I3

add an item between 100 and 105
eval(100,105) --> yes

I100
I102
I105
I2
I3

add an item between 100 and 102
eval(100,102) --> yes

I100
I101
I102
I105
I2
I3

add an item between 100 and 101
eval(100,101) --> no

I100
I1005
I101
I102
I105
I2
I3

and so on.
```

The output for
db.getCollection('items').find({}).sort({index: 1})

produces the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Would adding an index to your record set and then when you query you can get your result set sorted by that index not work in your case?

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

EDIT Update:

You can use sub-division of the index, eg:

insert between elements with indexA=2 and indexB=3, generating an insertIndex = (2+3)/2 = 2.5

However, in Javascript you would need to use floats which are max 17 decimals, same as MongoDB double.  You would need to account for this and if the rounding occurred, eg if insertIndex = indexA or = indexB then you hit the limitation and need to call a function to update the database and loop all elements to update their index with eg integers.  After doing this the first time, it's likely it wouldn't trigger often and would trigger less and less over time.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the order frequently changes and I would need to update the order property for all items when I change/insert a new one.

Comment: Wow. Having the same thought at the exact same moment. (I posted the same solution in a comment above :) ... I think this is actually the best way to deal with it

Comment: Why did you remove the solution? I was just about to mark it as answered

Comment: @Chris, I retracted it because you can't subdivide very far and hit the 17 decimial limitation of Javascript floats.

Comment: It could work, but you would have to know that your solution would never hit that subdivision limit, or if it did you handle it by refreshing all eg loop all and replace them with ordered integers.

Comment: It takes 57 iterations to hit the limit. But I could simply save the index number as a string which makes it practically unlimited. Do you have an idea if that would impact the sorting performance drastically? Or should I open a seperate question for this?

Comment: You can save it as a string, but you can't calculate it in Javascript because of the 17 digit limitation after that it rounds and the value would be the same as the original eg you can't subdivide any further. Also, sorting the string wouldn't work properly as 0.125, 0.25, 0.5 as a string would only sort if you appended 0's to the end of it to pad it eg to 17 characters. In this case, you still have to update all which could be tricky if multiple people append it simultaneously you would have to block updates while all elements index were updated with integers.

Comment: Why would it need any appended 0s? The order of 0.125,0.25,0.5 is correct when sorted as strings. I also found a way to avoid the calculation limit and will post it as an answer for discussion in a few minutes.

Comment: Ah, I haven't thought deeply on it my first instinct was that they are in reverse order eg 0.125 is read as a string as 125 and 0.5 is read as 5 so 125 is larger than 5 but you can just change sort order to descending. Looking forward to seeing your solution! Thinking 0.625 vs 0.0625 would be equal.. thats what i was thinking with appending zeros so all decimals end in zeros out to match the highest number of digits possible.